# Residue Calculus Integrable Model

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm currently working on the derivation of Bethe ansatz equations.

I have an equation like this:

$ z^{-1}\prod_{m=1,m\neq l}^{Q-1}\frac{q^2z-z_{m}}{z-z_{m}}+q^{-2}z
\prod_{m=1,m\neq l}^{Q-1}\frac{q^{-2}z-z_{m}}{z-z_{m}}-(z+z^{-1})=E,$

where $z\in \mathbb{C},q\in\mathbb{C}$ and $E$ is an energy eigenvalue.

Obviously, the poles exist at $z=0, z=\infty , z=z_{m}$. Since the lhs is meromorphic function and the rhs is a constant, to make them equal, I have to calculate the residues and null them.

For $z=0$ the problem is solved. But I have problem with the two other cases.

I tried to calculate the residue at $z=\infty$ and at $z=z_{m}$ via

$Res(f(z),z=\infty)=-Res(-z^{-2}f(1/z),z=0)$ and $ Res(f(z),z=z_{m})=\lim_{z\to z_{m}}(z-z_{m})\cdots$

The vanishing of the resiude at $z=z_{m}$ should give equations like this:

$z^2_{l}=q^{Q}\prod_{m=1,m\neq l}^{Q-1} \frac{q^2 z_{l} -z_{m}}{z_l-q^2z_{m}}$

But in both cases I failed. Please, can anybody help. I am grateful for any ideas.

Comment: ‘Calculate the residue and then null them’ what do you mean, practically?

Comment: I mean that the residues , e.g. at $z=z_{m}$ vanish if the parameters $\lbrace z_{l} \rbrace$  satisfy the above equation $z^2_{l}=\cdots$. Does this help you?